Why when I rotate the finger bones, the assigned vertices don't stay aligned with the bones?
when I rotate the finger bone, the vertices assigned to the bone rotate in the right direction but do not remain aligned with the bone. What could be the problem?
This is an image in T-Pose

And this is when I rotate the finger bone


They are probably assigned to other bones too

You don't have any weights assigned to your fingers, go to Weight Paint Mode to fix this.

I did "assign automatic weights"

you are right, I assigned to the hand bone all the vertices of the hand, including the fingers! Fixed this, now it works well!
Thanks a lot!

For issues like this, see the weight paint section at the end of my answer on this topic: Parenting Mesh to Bones Issue

Hello, Raffaele .. glad you have a fix! This looks more like a slip-up (easily made) Than a question requiring an answer in the archive for  future readers, so it's fair to close it. By all means edit for a re-open if you disagree.
